# Number of cyclic paths in a rectangular grid?

Tags: combinatorics

> If we start at the down-left corner or equivalently the origin and move only in the first quadrant, using only 4-directional moves, what are the number of ways to make a cyclic routes back to origin in exactly n-moves?

I think that if we denote $n_i$ as move in $i$-direction. then we have $n_u\ge n_d$ and $n_r\ge n_l$ anytime and also $n_u+n_l+n_r+n_d=n$, finally. So (let $n_u=k$):
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom n{2k}C_{k}C_{n/2-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\binom{n+2}{n/2+1}\binom{n/2+1}{k}\binom{n/2+1}{k+1}=\frac1{(n+2)(n+1)}\binom{n+2}{n/2+1}\binom{n+2}{n/2}$$
**Question:** Am I right? Is there any other easy or combinatoric way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear to be correct, though perhaps not the simplest approach.

It’s clear that $n$ must be even, so for convenience let $n=2m$. In any such path the number of horizontal moves must be even, so it must be $2k$ for some $k=0,\ldots,m$. For each of these values of $k$ there are $\binom{n}{2k}$ possible sets of positions for the horizontal moves. Within this set of positions there are $C_k$ possible sequences that avoid negative $x$-coordinates, and the there are $C_{m-k}$ possible sequences for the $n-2k$ vertical moves that avoid negative $y$-coordinates. The total is therefore

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}{2k}C_kC_{m-k}&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}k\binom{n-2k}{m-k}\frac1{(k+1)(m-k+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{2m}{k,k,m-k,m-k}\frac1{(k+1)(m-k+1)}\;.
\end{align*}$$

From this it’s not hard to calculate the values for $m=0,1,2$, and $3$: they are $1,2,10$, and $70$. Searching for this in the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org), we find that the first return is [OEIS A005568](https://oeis.org/A005568), one of whose comments identifies it as the sequence that we want. Better yet, it turns out that these are just the products of two consecutive Catalan numbers:

$$\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}{2k}C_kC_{m-k}=C_mC_{m+1}=\frac1{(m+1)(m+2)}\binom{2m}m\binom{2m+2}{m+1}\;.$$

Comment: Infact the final answer is same

Comment: @ADG: You’re right; my apologies. I’ll change the wording.