# Number of paths between two points in the first Quadrant.

Tags: combinatorics

[Extension of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756906/number-of-cyclic-paths-in-a-rectangular-grid)]

> We can move in 4-directions and we need to reach $(0,b)$ from $(a,0)$ in exactly $n$ steps keeping in the first quadrant ($x\ge0$ and $y\ge0$) [$a,b\ge0$]

Similar to previous problem, $a+n_r\ge n_l$, $n_u\ge n_d$ and finally $a+n_r-n_l=0$, $n_u-n_d=b$, $n_u+n_d+n_l+n_r=n$. (let $n_u=k$, a similar logic as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Second_proof) is used below)
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n+a+b}2}\binom n{2k-b}\left(\binom{2k-b}{k}-\binom{2k-b}{k+1}\right)\left(\binom{n+b-2k}{\frac{n+a+b}2-k}-\binom{n+b-2k}{\frac{n+a+b}2-k+1}\right)\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n+a+b}2}\binom n{2k-b}\frac{(b+1)(a+1)}{(2k-b+1)(n+b-2k+1)}\binom{2k-b+1}{k+1}\binom{n+b-2k+1}{\frac{n+a+b}2-k+1}\\
=\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}\binom{n+2}{\frac{n-a+b}2+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n+a+b}2}\binom{\frac{n-a+b}2+1}{k+1}\binom{\frac{n+a+b}2+1}{k-b}\\
=\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}\binom{n+2}{\frac{n-a+b}2+1}\binom{n+2}{\frac{n-a-b}2}$$
And at $a=0,b=0$:
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\binom{n+2}{\frac{n}2+1}\binom{n+2}{\frac{n}2}$$
the solution seems to agree with previous result.
**Question:** It seems correct. What do you say? Is there any easy way?

Comment: I imagine that (with the title "first quadrant") $a>0$ and $b>0$. But what are your four directions ? OK for North and West, but if you allow East or South, infinite loops are generated ...

Comment: @JeanMarie a>0, b>0 first quadrant (x>=0 & y>=0), no infinite loops as total moves =n, each move 4 direction N,E,W and S as u said

Comment: @JeanMarie actually $a,b\ge0$

Comment: So basically we are trying to find the lattice paths

Comment: Yes but its just that you can go anywhere in fitst quadrant, cross yourself any number of atimes and reach the final point